Incompatible list lengths when passing a list of symbols into function parameter?
I have a function that filters on a master table as the below:
condSel:{[tabl;colNames;colValues]
    wc: {(in;x;enlist y)}.'flip(colNames;colValues);
    res: ?[tabl;wc;0b;()];
    res

I can apply this separately to filter on two columns within my master table:
res_fltr1: condSel[t;enlist `s; enlist `s1];
res_fltr2: condSel[t;enlist `name; enlist `$("P Willy";"D Reim")];

But it is only when I try to combine these two columns inside the filter function that I receive an incompatible list error that I am very unsure on how to fix:
res_fltr: condSel[t;`s`name;`s1`$("P Willy";"D Reim")];

What am I missing here? If I attempt this on columns s and p instead where I would pass one symbol for each column, then there are no issues.
res_fltr: condSel[t;`s`p;`s1`p1];

Dummy table below:
s  p  qty   name
------------------
s1 p1 300  F James
s1 p2 200  P Willy
s1 p3 400  P Willy
s1 p4 200  D Reim
s4 p5 100  M Oxhart
s1 p6 100  P Willy
...


This syntax is incorrect:
q)`s1`$("P Willy";"D Reim")
'type
  [0]  `s1`$("P Willy";"D Reim")

You need to join them using ,:
q)`s1,`$("P Willy";"D Reim")
`s1`P Willy`D Reim


res_fltr: condSel[t;'name's;'$("P Willy";"D Reim"),'s1];   --->  does not work, returns a "mismatched types" error

Have you even tried running your third parameter expression at the console outside the function? It gives a type error. Your syntax is incorrect. Secondly, join each both ,' is not the same as join ,. You are creating a list of lists with join each both, your function is expecting a single list.

Hey, I am using an apostrophe here instead of a tilde due to Stack's syntax. I did indeed use tildes and was not trying to join each and it still does not work. Oddly enough, swapping the two variables around as you did works fine, but if I do it with name first then s it does not seem to work.

The syntax is not correct. kdb+ is evaluated right to left, you are attempting to join a symbol to a list of strings and then convert that to a symbol

Ahh okay I understand that, doing (`$("P Willy";"D Reim")),'s1 seems to join them correctly but that creates a list of three symbols giving a length error given I pass only two columns. How can I amend the above so that it passes in two symbols, with one being a list of strings converted to symbols and the other just being the symbol s1?

((`$("P Willy";"D Reim"));`s1) seems to works, thanks for your help!
